# SQL3116W The field value in row and column is missing, but the target column is not nullable. How to specify to use Column Default

Tags: db2

I'm using LOAD command to get data into a table where one of the columns has the default value of the current timestamp. I had NULL value in the data being read as I thought it would cause the table to use the default value but based on above error that's not the case. How do I avoid the above error in this case?
Here is the full command, input file is text file: LOAD FROM  ${LOADDIR}/${InputFile}.exp OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL| INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE NONRECOVERABLE

Comment: please edit your question to show your load command, and the type of the input file.  File type ASC supports method L which lets you specify the null indicators for the column-numbers which would then allow Db2 to use the default. You can also check MODIFIED BY USEFEFAULTS .

Comment: I ended up doing a workaround where I passed the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
LOAD FROM ${LOADDIR}/${InputFile}.exp OF DEL MODIFIED BY USEDEFAULTS COLDEL| INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE NONRECOVERABLE
```

This modifier `usedefaults` has been available in Db2-LUW since V7.x, as long as they are fully serviced (i.e. have had the final fixpack correctly applied).

Note that some Db2-LUW versions place restrictions on usage of `usedefaults` modifier, as detailed in the documentation. For example, restrictions relating to use with other modifiers, or modes or target table type.

Always specify your Db2-server version and platform when asking for help because the answer can depende on these facts.

Comment: I'm getting this message - SQL3016N  An unexpected keyword "USEDEFAULTS" was found in the filetmod
parameter for the filetype.

Comment: What is the db2level output on the db2 server?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which columns from the input file go into which columns of the table using METHOD P - if you omit the column you want the default for it will throw a warning but the default will be populated:

```
$ db2 "create table testtab1 (cola int, colb int, colc timestamp not null default)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$ cat tt1.del
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,99
$ db2 "load from tt1.del of del method P(1,2) insert into testtab1 (cola, colb)"
SQL27967W  The COPY NO recoverability parameter of the Load has been converted
to NONRECOVERABLE within the HADR environment.

SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file
"/home/db2inst1/tt1.del".

SQL3500W  The utility is beginning the "LOAD" phase at time "07/12/2021
10:14:04.362385".

SQL3112W  There are fewer input file columns specified than database columns.

SQL3519W  Begin Load Consistency Point. Input record count = "0".

SQL3520W  Load Consistency Point was successful.

SQL3110N  The utility has completed processing.  "3" rows were read from the
input file.

SQL3519W  Begin Load Consistency Point. Input record count = "3".

SQL3520W  Load Consistency Point was successful.

SQL3515W  The utility has finished the "LOAD" phase at time "07/12/2021
10:14:04.496670".


Number of rows read         = 3
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows loaded       = 3
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows deleted      = 0
Number of rows committed    = 3

$ db2 "select * from testtab1"

COLA        COLB        COLC
----------- ----------- --------------------------
          1           1 2021-12-07-10.14.04.244232
          2           2 2021-12-07-10.14.04.244232
          3           3 2021-12-07-10.14.04.244232

  3 record(s) selected.
```